# Xdebug on remote production server from local machine

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a problem with setting up remote xdebug session. On remote production server i have the following config

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on

xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.trace_output_dir = /home/sh.mathster.ru/logs
xdebug.remote_log = /home/sh.mathster.ru/logs/xdebug.txt
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
```

Also i setting up my PhpStorm6 (Xdebug by default and DBGp with my id and IDE key).

In action, i turn on listener in PhpStorm, turn on debug in Chrome extension (extension from JetBrains) and refresh production host (in browser). 
But everytime i get 500 error with message about execution time limit (30 or 60 sec, no matter, it always crushes)

So, how to bring this work?....

Comment: Can you post the log files?

Comment: Which one? I have no logs from xdebug, only my remote host error/access logs

Comment: Can you post output of phpinfo? Is xdebug installed?

Comment: Yes, i see xdebug section. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0951pg468c